# Archimedean places of a number field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $K$ be a number field with an Archimedean absolute value $|\cdot |$ and let $\bar{K}$ be the completion of $K$ wrt this valuation. Then $\bar{K}\cong \mathbb R $ or $\mathbb C$.

My question is:

> Does this imply that the Archimedean places of $K$ correspond bijectively to the real embeddings $K\hookrightarrow \mathbb R$ and complex conjugate pairs of embeddings $K\hookrightarrow \mathbb C$?

Are there other ways to show this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Indeed, you are correct about the bijection. Another way to show it would be to consider, for $x \in K$, the $|x|_{\sigma} =|\sigma(x)|$ if $\sigma$ is a real embedding real and $|x|_{\sigma} = |\sigma(x)|^2 = |\bar{\sigma}(x)|^2$ if $\sigma$ is a complex embedding. It isn't too hard to prove that these are Archimedean and not equivalent, though I'm unsure about how to prove that every other Archimedean absolute value on $K$ must be equivalent to one of these. As a side-note, you may wish to have a look at Chapter 2 of Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory*...

Comment: ... in particular to [section 3](https://books.google.it/books?id=hS3qCAAAQBAJ&pg=PR6&dq=neukirch+algebraic+number+theory&hl=en&sa=X&ei=f0drVdOQAcb3UJCngaAF&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: This is also true in the non-archimedean case with a slight modification: there is a bijection between places of $v$ lying over $p$ and $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_p/\mathbf{Q}_p)$-conjugacy classes of $\mathbf{Q}_p$-embeddings of $K_v \hookrightarrow \overline{\mathbf{Q}}_p$.